# Why `getBoundingClientRect()` and `getComputedStyle()` give different values

Tags: javascript, html, css

Why `ball.getBoundingClientRect().bottom` and  `parseInt(getComputedStyle(ball).bottom)` give out different values here?

```js
console.log( ball.getBoundingClientRect().bottom );
console.log( parseInt(getComputedStyle(ball).bottom) );
```

```css
.ball {
  height           : 5rem;
  width            : 5rem;
  background-color : salmon;
  border-radius    : 50%;
  position         : relative;
  top              : 40vh;
  left             : 45vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="ball"></div>
```

I was expecting the values to be same.

Comment: Because the [CSS `bottom` property](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning) and the [`bottom` property of a `DOMRect`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) have completely different semantics.

Comment: By just referring to the [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and by doing a small research on the returned values - you would have found your answer pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` gets the distance in pixels from the top of the **viewport (window)** and the bottom of the **element**. So if a box is 40px and it's 10px away form the top of the window, the `getBoundingClientRect().bottom` returns 50

`getBoundingClientRect` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

The `getComputedStyle(element)` get the **rendered css** (final result with all styles applied) from the element, so if you define bottom position to 10px, it's gonna return 10.

`getComputedStyle` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle